# Retrieve Last updated records based on WHERE condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I had a table 'User_Relation' which contains relation, last-updated columns.It contains bunch of records based on father,mother,son relations each.

I need to retrieve latest record for all relations at a time using query.No need to use cursor.

[image]

This is my desired output

[image]

Comment: post sample data and Required output

Comment: from that table i need last-updated record for each relation

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751913/retrieving-last-record-in-each-group-from-database-sql-server-2005-2008

Comment: @Nazeer_hanne Please give clarity about what you are expecting as output or post sample output what is your required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using With Cte:

```
;WITH cte
      AS (SELECT *,
                 Row_number()
                   OVER(
                     partition BY relationfamily
                     ORDER BY lastmodify DESC) AS result
          FROM   User_Relation)
 SELECT relationfamily,
        lastmodify
 FROM   cte
 WHERE  result = 1
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations.

Comment: yes this works with your window function.I am able to get each entire row at a time.Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Check the below query and hope this helps you:

```
SELECT relationfamily, MAX(lastmodify)
FROM User_Relation
WHERE mainuser = 'sivabrahma'
GROUP BY relationfamily
```

Comment: SO is asking for each relation. May be this will not give expected output @paresh J

Comment: @mohan111: i HAVE USED GROUP BY I THINK IT WILL GROUP EACH RELATION WITH THEIR MAX DATES FOR ME.

Comment: @Nazeer_hanne: Please check the output and if it matches your expected result you can upvote my answer.

Comment: @Paresh,But i need to get all colums in a row instead of selected columns..look at table once again..I had edited my table..I got fixed this by using window function...Thanks for your guidance...