# SQL - Get latest records based on last date

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a `SQL Server` table with the following data:

[image]

I need to get the latest records for each currency so the result should be:

[image]

> Is it possible to get this result in just one select without doing nested selects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Comment: *without doing nested selects*: Why the restriction?

Comment: And another duplicate specific to SQL Server using the Row_Number function:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751913/retrieving-last-record-in-each-group-from-database-sql-server-2005-2008

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ORDER BY` with `TIES` as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM Src
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Currency ORDER BY ID DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the window functions

```
;with cteBase as (
    Select *,RowNr=Row_Number() over(Partition By Currency Order By Date Desc) from YourTable
)
Select * from cteBase Where RowNr=1
```

Comment: Just curious on the down vote.  That said, I DID give an UpVote for Pawel's WITH TIES. His was a better solution

Answer (score -1):

since your records are entered at the day of RATE update(seams that way), this should work...
(please modify the limit as to match the number of currencies in your table)

SELECT ID,DISTINCT(CURRENCY),DATE,RATE FROM table ORDER BY CURRENCY,-DATE LIMIT 0,3