# Select Latest or most recent date in SQL query

Tags: sql

I am running a query in SQL on our EHR/EMR database. I am primarily looking at an assessment that is done by a nurse during each patient encounter/visit and looking to return an answer for the most recent assessment date along with some other info. I have the query created and all the data is coming over, however, it is returning all assessment dates and the answers instead of just the latest date and answer. I'll attach the full code below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    MAX(PTA.ASSESSMENT_DATE) AS Max_Date, 
    SAQ.QUESTION_TEXT, SAA.ANSWER_TEXT, dbo.PT_BASIC.PATIENT_CODE,  
    dbo.PT_BASIC.NAME_FULL
FROM
    dbo.PTC_ASSESSMENT_ANSWER AS PAA 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.PTC_ASSESSMENT AS PTA ON PTA.ASSESSMENT_ID = PAA.ASSESSMENT_ID 
                              AND PTA.PATIENT_ID = PAA.PATIENT_ID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.SYS_ASSESSMENT_POINTER AS SAP ON SAP.POINTER_ID = PAA.POINTER_ID   
INNER JOIN
    dbo.SYS_ASSESSMENT_QUESTION AS SAQ ON SAQ.QUESTION_ID = SAP.QUESTION_ID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.SYS_ASSESSMENT_ANSWER AS SAA ON SAA.ANSWER_ID = SAP.ANSWER_ID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.PT_BASIC ON PTA.PATIENT_ID = dbo.PT_BASIC.PATIENT_ID
WHERE
    (PTA.ASSESSMENT_DATE BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-09-05 00:00:00', 102) 
                             AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-10-12 00:00:00', 102))
GROUP BY 
    dbo.PT_BASIC.PATIENT_CODE, dbo.PT_BASIC.NAME_FULL, SAQ.QUESTION_TEXT, 
    SAA.ANSWER_TEXT
HAVING      
    (SAA.ANSWER_TEXT LIKE '%LEVEL % -%')
```

The current output would be something similar to this:
9/5/2017   PATIENT ABC    Answer1
9/6/2017   PATIENT ABC    Answer2
9/7/2017   PATIENT ABC    Answer3
9/6/2017   PATIENT XYZ    Answer4

What I am expecting is:

9/7/2017   PATIENT ABC    Answer3
9/6/2017   PATIENT XYZ    Answer4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving last record in each group from database - SQL Server 2005/2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751913/retrieving-last-record-in-each-group-from-database-sql-server-2005-2008)

Comment: Cross Apply instead of inner join.

Comment: What RDBMS and version? and what is the distribution of PTC_Assessments to Answers?  are there many assessments to each answer? or just a few and will the distribution change over time?

Comment: **GROUP BY** produces uniquely defined rows, there is NEVER a need to `select distinct` as well (in a single select query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of SQL Server supports it, using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` is an efficient and simple method for arriving at "latest" (or "earliest") rows from a single table. However as we know so little about your data model it isn't easy to guess how to reduce the rows to just the "lastest answer" which probably requires a more complex subquery. However you can still use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` on that subquery. I suspect that the nature of questions and answers is that the table aliases SAP, SAQ, SAA may all need to be involved in this subquery.

Note that instead of directly joining PTA this is now a subquery and the join condition to the outer query requires that `RN=1` which is the row with the "latest" date.

```
SELECT
      MAX(PTA.ASSESSMENT_DATE) AS Max_Date
    , SAQ.QUESTION_TEXT
    , SAA.ANSWER_TEXT
    , dbo.PT_BASIC.PATIENT_CODE
    , dbo.PT_BASIC.NAME_FULL
FROM dbo.PTC_ASSESSMENT_ANSWER AS PAA
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT
            *
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PATIENT_ID
                               ORDER BY ASSESSMENT_DATE DESC) AS RN
      FROM dbo.PTC_ASSESSMENT
      WHERE ASSESSMENT_DATE BETWEEN  '20170905' AND '20171012'
      ) AS PTA ON PTA.ASSESSMENT_ID = PAA.ASSESSMENT_ID
            AND PTA.PATIENT_ID = PAA.PATIENT_ID
            AND PTA.RN = 1
INNER JOIN dbo.SYS_ASSESSMENT_POINTER AS SAP ON SAP.POINTER_ID = PAA.POINTER_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.SYS_ASSESSMENT_QUESTION AS SAQ ON SAQ.QUESTION_ID = SAP.QUESTION_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.SYS_ASSESSMENT_ANSWER AS SAA ON SAA.ANSWER_ID = SAP.ANSWER_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.PT_BASIC ON PTA.PATIENT_ID = dbo.PT_BASIC.PATIENT_ID
WHERE SAA.ANSWER_TEXT LIKE '%LEVEL % -%'
GROUP BY
      dbo.PT_BASIC.PATIENT_CODE
    , dbo.PT_BASIC.NAME_FULL
    , SAQ.QUESTION_TEXT
    , SAA.ANSWER_TEXT
```

1. `select distinct` is not required on this query (or any similar query using `GROUP BY`)
2. yyymmdd is the safest date literal in SQL Server, you don't need the converts using style 102
3. your having clause should be moved to a where clause as it does not evaluate any aggregated value

Answer (score 0):

Cross apply allows you to use a correlated query and chive the top most  n records ordered by date desc for each patient assessment.  (after review maybe you just need patient?)

Perhaps just change:

```
INNER JOIN
    dbo.PTC_ASSESSMENT AS PTA ON PTA.ASSESSMENT_ID = PAA.ASSESSMENT_ID 
                              AND PTA.PATIENT_ID = PAA.PATIENT_ID
```

TO:

```
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * 
             FROM dbo.PTC_ASSESSMENT PTA2 
             WHERE PTA2.ASSESSMENT_ID = PAA.ASSESSMENT_ID 
            /*AND PTA2.PATIENT_ID = PAA.PATIENT_ID*/
             ORDER BY PTA2.Assessment_date desc) PTA
```

GIVING YOU: (I left the /*AND PTA2.PATIENT_ID = PAA.PATIENT_ID*/   --I think you can omit this. I left the  */ in place but it's not needed)

```
SELECT MAX(PTA.ASSESSMENT_DATE) AS Max_Date
     , SAQ.QUESTION_TEXT
     , SAA.ANSWER_TEXT
     , dbo.PT_BASIC.PATIENT_CODE
     , dbo.PT_BASIC.NAME_FULL
FROM dbo.PTC_ASSESSMENT_ANSWER AS PAA 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * 
             FROM dbo.PTC_ASSESSMENT PTA2 
             WHERE PTA2.ASSESSMENT_ID = PAA.ASSESSMENT_ID   --I think you can omit this.
               /*AND PTA2.PATIENT_ID = PAA.PATIENT_ID*/
             ORDER BY PTA2.Assessment_date desc) PTA
INNER JOIN dbo.SYS_ASSESSMENT_POINTER AS SAP 
   ON SAP.POINTER_ID = PAA.POINTER_ID   
INNER JOIN dbo.SYS_ASSESSMENT_QUESTION AS SAQ 
   ON SAQ.QUESTION_ID = SAP.QUESTION_ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.SYS_ASSESSMENT_ANSWER AS SAA 
   ON SAA.ANSWER_ID = SAP.ANSWER_ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.PT_BASIC 
   ON PTA.PATIENT_ID = dbo.PT_BASIC.PATIENT_ID
WHERE (PTA.ASSESSMENT_DATE BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-09-05 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-10-12 00:00:00', 102))
GROUP BY dbo.PT_BASIC.PATIENT_CODE
       , dbo.PT_BASIC.NAME_FULL
       , SAQ.QUESTION_TEXT
       , SAA.ANSWER_TEXT
HAVING (SAA.ANSWER_TEXT LIKE '%LEVEL % -%')
```

It appears you're not concerned about patients w/o assessments as all your joins are inner or we could use OUTER APPPLY to be sure to keep all answers regardless if an assessment has been provided.

Alternatively you could use a row_number() logic ( Tab Alleman's link has this covered) and a cte; but if cross apply is available might as well use it here.

Comment: I made those changes and now the results are better but if a patient has 2 different answers on a different day I am getting both of those listed. For instance:  9/6/17   Patient1   Answer1,  9/7/17 Patient1 Answer2. I'm not getting every assessment answer but just those that are unique answers now when all I really need is the latest answer.

Comment: then eliminate the assessment_ID as part of the correlated query I think.  I've put comment blocks around the section I think you can remove in the above answer /* */

Comment: Getting closer I think. The max date field is now showing the latest assessment date but I am getting several different answers. For Patient1 I am getting Answer1, Answer2, and Answer3 but the dates for all 3 are showing the latest date though all 3 answers were on different days.

Answer (score 0):

Please include `order by PTA.ASSESSMENT_DATE DESC` to see the latest records at the top.