# SQL Remove duplicates based on value of Text field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to remove duplicate rows based on value of a text field (Comment).

The records are considered duplicates because they have the same CommentID and PersonID.

Basically, I need to keep the latest NON NULL comment.

There are 4 possible scenarios:

**Scenario 1:**
    If the first row does NOT have a Comment (null/empty) AND the second row does NOT have a Comment (null/empty)
    Then remove the first row (keep the latest comment even though it's null/empty)

**Scenario 2:**
    If the first row does NOT have a Comment (null/empty) AND the second row HAS a Comment
    Then remove the first row (keep the latest comment)

**Scenario 3:**
    If the first row HAS a Comment AND the second row HAS a Comment
    Then remove the first row (keep the latest comment)

**Scenario 4:**
    If the first row HAS a Comment AND the second row does NOT have a Comment (null/empty)
    Then remove the second row (keep the first comment)

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks,
John.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PersonComment](
    [PersonCommentID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CommentID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Comment] [text] NULL,
    [PersonID] [int] NOT NULL
) 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PersonComment]
    ([PersonCommentID]
    ,[CommentID]
    ,[Comment]
    ,[PersonID])
VALUES
    (1,555,'Hello',123),
    (2,555,'Hello World',123),
    (3,444,'Hello',112),
    (4,444,'Hello World',112),
    (5,333,'Hello World',111),
    (6,333,NULL,111),
    (7,222,NULL,100),
    (8,222,'Hello',100),
    (9,111,NULL,99),
    (10,111,NULL,99)

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[PersonComment] WITH (NOLOCK)
```

[image]

Comment: You could group by CommentID and PersonID and select last. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4751992/2091230) shows a way to do it.

Comment: Thanks marc-s / Justinas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned you should use `ROW_NUMBER` to order your table grouped by `CommentID` and `PersonID`. And order by length of `Comment` column.

In your DDL's `Comment` column is type of `text`. It's deprecated, you should avoid using `text` data type.

```
with cte as (
    select 
        *
        , row_number() over (
                partition by CommentID, PersonID 
                order by case when isnull(datalength(Comment), 0) = 0 then 1 else 0 end, PersonCommentID desc
        ) rn
    from 
        [dbo].[PersonComment]
)

delete from cte where rn > 1
```

Comment: Ahh... order by datalength(comment), that's the bit I was missing. Thanks a million uzi !!!!

Answer (score 0):

the easy way is to use CTE in this part , a sample below

```
WITH CTE AS(
 SELECT  [PersonCommentID]
  , RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY    [Comment]  
 Order by [Comment])
 FROM  PersonComment
)

DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Comment: Hi Ali, Thanks for responding so quickly. The Comment field is text type so I had to convert in order to use it  . . . unfortunately your solution removes two extra rows, only half the rows should be deleted (5 rows)