# Retrieving last record in each group from database with additional max() condition in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance

This is a follow-up question to [Retrieving last record in each group from database - SQL Server 2005/2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751913/retrieving-last-record-in-each-group-from-database-sql-server-2005-2008)

In the answers, this example was provided to retrieve last record for a group of parameters (example below retrieves last updates for each value in computername):

```
 select t.*
 from t
 where t.lastupdate = (select max(t2.lastupdate)
                  from t t2
                  where t2.computername = t.computername
                 );
```

In my case, however,  "lastupdate" is not unique (some updates come in batches and have same lastupdate value, and if two updates of "computername" come in the same batch, you will get non-unique output for "computername + lastupdate"). 
Suppose I also have field "rowId" that is just auto-incremental. The mitigation would be to include in the query another criterion for a  max('rowId') field.

NB:  while the example employs time-specific name "lastupdate", the actual selection criteria may not be related to the time at all.

I, therefore, like to ask, what would be the **most performant** query that selects the last record in each group based both on "group-defining parameter" (in the case above, "computername") and on maximal rowId?

Comment: i think 
Ranking Functions 
 might help 

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have uniqueness, then `row_number()` is simpler:

```
 select t.*
 from (select t.*,
              row_number() over (partition by computername order by lastupdate, rowid desc) as seqnum
       from t
      ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

With the right indexes, the correlated subquery is usually faster.  However, the performance difference is not that great.