# Select specific records in a table

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server.The first contains a list of clients and the second contains a list of activities for each client. How can I set up a query to select only the last activity for each of the clients?

For example:

- Client1 has Act1, Act2, Act3, Act4
- Client2 has Act1, Act2

I want to see Client1--->Act4 and Client2--->Act2.

There is a way to do this?

EDIT:
I merged the two tables in a cursor, now I have this situation (there are also other fields but they are not importants):

```
ID             DATE
00001         25/04/2019 09.20
00001         30/04/2019 10.00
00002         23/04/2019 09.00
00002         29/04/2019 11.00
00003         NULL
```

My need now is obtain this result:

```
ID             DATE
00001         30/04/2019 10.00
00002         29/04/2019 11.00
00003         NULL
```

I tried with:

```
 SELECT temp.* ;
 FROM temp
 WHERE TTOC(temp.date,1) IN (SELECT TTOC(MAX(t.date),1) FROM temp FULL OUTER JOIN t ON temp.ID == t.ID GROUP BY temp.ID)
```

where t is one of the two original tables before the merge. It works, but the user without any info in the DATE field is not shown. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you define "last"? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving last record in each group from database - SQL Server 2005/2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751913/retrieving-last-record-in-each-group-from-database-sql-server-2005-2008)

Comment: Last is here intendend as "Last Inserted Activity"

Comment: There's no such thing as "last inserted activity" if there's no column that defines when was the activity inserted.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a great place to start.

Comment: Of course there is a field with the date of the last activity... The example you pointed before seems to do exactly what I need... I have to study it deeper...

Answer (score 0):

```
select Client
       ,reverse(left(reverse(Act), charindex(',', reverse(Act)) -1)) as LastAct
from table
```

How it works:
reverse the entire string, then find the first comma, which is used to be last comma, then trim string left to it, the reverse it back.

Comment: @meltigel,no problem, let me know if you need more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

For your `temp` table, you only need `group by id`:

```
SELECT id, max(date) lastact
FROM temp
GROUP BY id
```

If you want to see the other columns too:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM temp t LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT id, max(date) lastact
  FROM temp
  GROUP BY id
) g on g.id = t.id and g.lastact = t.date
```

Comment: All the fields are in temp, non in t. In one table I have all the info about the Clients, and in the second (this example is t) I have the info about activities performed by each client (appointments, calls, and so on)... I made a cursor with all the fields from Clients and with the only DATE field from activity... your suggestion doesn't work because the fields I need are inside temp, not t.

Comment: My `t` is an alias of `temp`.