# How do i get the latest user udpated column value in a table based on timestamp entry on a different table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temp table #StatusInfo with the following data

```
+---------+--------------+-------+-------------------------+--+
| OrderNo | GroupLineNum | Type1 | UpdateDate              |  |
+---------+--------------+-------+-------------------------+--+
| Order85 | NULL         | 1     | 2019-11-25 05:15:55.000 |  |
+---------+--------------+-------+-------------------------+--+
| Order86 | NULL         | 1     | 2019-11-25 05:15:55.000 |  |
+---------+--------------+-------+-------------------------+--+
| Order86 | 2            | 2     | 2019-11-25 05:32:23.773 |  |
+---------+--------------+-------+-------------------------+--+
| Order87 | NULL         | 1     | 2019-11-25 05:15:55.000 |  |
+---------+--------------+-------+-------------------------+--+
| Order87 | 1            | 2     | 2019-11-25 05:43:37.637 |  | B
+---------+--------------+-------+-------------------------+--+
| Order87 | 2            | 2     | 2019-11-25 05:42:32.390 |  | A
+---------+--------------+-------+-------------------------+--+
| Order88 | NULL         | 1     | 2019-11-25 06:35:13.000 |  |
+---------+--------------+-------+-------------------------+--+
| Order88 | 1            | 2     | 2019-11-25 06:39:16.170 |  |
+---------+--------------+-------+-------------------------+--+
```

Any update the user does on an order will be pulled into this temp table. Type 1 column with value 2 denotes a 'Required Date' field change by the user. The timestamp when the user made the change is the last column.

I have another temp table #LineInfo with the following data. This table is created by joining other tables and a left join with the above table too. The 'LineNum' column from below table will match the 'GroupLineNum' column in the above table for Type1=2

```
+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------------------+-------+
| OrderNo | RowNumber | LineNum | TotalCost  | ReqDate                 | Type1 |
+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------------------+-------+
| Order85 | 1         | 1       | 309.110000 | 2019-10-30 23:59:00.000 | 1     |
+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------------------+-------+
| Order85 | 2         | 2       | 265.560000 | 2019-10-30 23:59:00.000 | 1     |
+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------------------+-------+
| Order86 | 1         | 1       | 309.110000 | 2019-10-30 23:59:00.000 | 1     |
+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------------------+-------+
| Order86 | 2         | 2       | 265.560000 | 2019-12-28 23:59:00.000 | 2     |
+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------------------+-------+
| Order87 | 1         | 1       | 309.110000 | 2020-01-31 23:59:00.000 | 2     |
+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------------------+-------+
| Order87 | 2         | 2       | 265.560000 | 2020-01-01 23:59:00.000 | 2     |
+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------------------+-------+
| Order88 | 1         | 1       | 309.110000 | 2019-11-29 23:59:00.000 | 2     |
+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------------------+-------+
| Order88 | 2         | 2       | 265.560000 | 2019-12-31 23:59:00.000 | 2     |
+---------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------------------+-------+
```

I will be joining #lineInfo with other tables to generate a new table with only one record for an orderno. Its grouped by orderno.

What I need to do is ensure that the new selectquery will have a column 'ReqDate' which will be the latest ReqDate value for the order.

For example, Order87 has two lines in the order. User updated Line 2 first at '2019-11-25 05:42:32.390' as seen in the row marked 'A' followed by Line 1 marked B @ '2019-11-25 05:43:37.637 ' from the first table.
The new query should have the data from LineInfo and only the 'ReqDate' value matching the 'LineNum' that has the maximum of 'UpdateDate' column for Type1=2 and group by orderno.
So in our example, the output should have the ReqDate value '2020-01-31 23:59:00.000'.

In short, an order should have the most recently updated required date. Order can have multiple line items where reqdate is udpated. If there is no entry in #StatusInfo table with Type2 for an order, then any one of the ReqDate value from the #LineInfo table will suffice. Maybe the first line

I wrote something like this but it doesnt pull orders without any entry in StatusInfo table. Those orders will have a default value even though user didnt udpate and i am not sure how to join the result of this with LineInfo table to set the latest value

```
Select SIT.Orderno, max_date,grouplinenum
from #StatusInfo SIT
inner join 
(SELECT Orderno, MAX(ActDate) as max_date
FROM #StatusInfo SI
WHERE SI.Type1=2
GROUP BY SI.Orderno)a
on a.Orderno = SIT.Orderno and a.max_date = SIT.ActDate
```

Comment: *"Any update the user does on an order will be pulled into this temp table."* This doesn't sound like a very temporary temporary table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving last record in each group from database - SQL Server 2005/2008](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4751913/3484879)

Comment: @Larnu You are right. There is another table that records these user actions but i filter those records based on some condition and creating the above StatusInfo temp table

Comment: @Larnu The link you mentioned has all the data in the same table. Mine is spread in two and then i have to display the same table but with a common value. That is where I am confused

Comment: Don't think in tables, think in datasets. A query with a `JOIN` returns 1 dataset; not 2.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. I created the blow CTE to load orders with req date change in order of Updated date and assigned it row number. Record with row number 1 will be the most recently updated date

```
    ;WITH cteLatestReqDate AS ( --We need to pull the latest ReqDate value the user set. So we are are ordering the SIT table by ActDate and assigning a row number and respective line's required date here
        SELECT SIT.OrderNo, SIT.UpdateDate, SIT.GroupLineNum, LLI.ReqDate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SIT.OrderNo ORDER BY ActDate DESC) AS RowNum
        FROM #StatusInfo SIT INNER JOIN #LineLevelInfo LLI ON SIT.OrderNo = OI.OrderNo AND SIT.GroupLineNum = LLI.LineNum
        WHERE SIT.Type1 = 2
    )
```

and then I added the below condition to my select query. Below select query is partial

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN MAX(LRD.ReqDate) IS NULL THEN CAST(FORMAT(MAX(LLI.ReqDate), 'yyMMdd') AS NVARCHAR(10))
        ELSE CAST(FORMAT(MAX(LRD.ReqDate), 'yyMMdd') AS NVARCHAR(10)) END AS LatestReqDate
FROM #LineLevelInfo LLI
LEFT JOIN(SELECT * FROM cteLatestReqDate WHERE RowNum = 1)LRD ON LRD.OrderNo = LLI.OrderNo And LRD.GroupLineNum = LLI.LineNum
```