# Select only Max Count from Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-synapse

I want to get only the max count from a table per day.  So, per day, if all I have is a zero in Cnt, grab one record, and if the value is greater than zero, grab that specific record.  A simple MAX() will not work because I have different prices for the same day.

Here is an image of my table.  I want to keep the rows in green.  Maybe it's a self join, based on ID and date.  Just thinking out loud here.

[image]

I am using SQL Server Data Warehouse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving last record in each group from database - SQL Server 2005/2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751913/retrieving-last-record-in-each-group-from-database-sql-server-2005-2008)

Comment: Images of data are useless....[Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure MAX is exactly what you need here. Something like this. This would retrieve the exact rows you state you want from your sample data.

```
select max(Cnt)
    , Dt
    , ID
from YourTable
group by Dt
    , ID
```

Given new understanding I think you may need something like this. This will return the entire row that you are interested in.

```
select *
from
(
    select ID
        , P1
        , P1
        , P1
        , P1
        , P1
        , P1
        , Cnt
        , Firm
        , Sys
        , Dt
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by ID, Dt order by Cnt desc)
    from YourTable
) x
where x.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Strange formatting with the comma on the newline, and you probably don't need the ID, but yes I think the secret is in the group by.

Comment: Not really odd.  Many prefer having a comma at the start of the line, @robbpriestley, as people can easily comment the line out. Others (like myself) put them at the end.

Comment: You are right Sean, but I need the all the columns with prices too.  This makes me think...maybe I need to apply your logic and mark these rows with some kind of counter, and then select all fields from these specific rows.

Comment: @ASH see my updated answer. I think this may be what you are looking for.

Comment: @robbpriestley some people like it trailing, others (like myself) prefer it leading. I also prefer column aliases at the beginning using Alias = Column instead of the rather common Value as Alias. Neither is right or wrong, just preference. I find it easier to read and manipulate during development with this format. :D