# SQL Server : selecting the Max Date/time of 2 rows that have the same value in the same column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
Date                     Id   Name   ClockinOrOut
-------------------------------------------------
2019-12-19 10:24:00.000  4    Bob   In
2019-12-19 15:26:10.000  4    Bob   Out
2019-12-19 12:17:36.000  800  Gary  In
2019-12-19 08:41:21.000  800  Gary  Out
```

I can't seem to get this output with the most recent date/time based off of Id and doesn't matter whether the ClockInOrOut is In or Out, even with using the `MAX()` function

```
Date                     Id   Name   ClockinOrOut
-------------------------------------------------
2019-12-19 15:26:10.000  4    Bob   Out
2019-12-19 12:17:36.000  800  Gary  In
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751913/retrieving-last-record-in-each-group-from-database-sql-server-2005-2008

Comment: the table have an autoincremental id ?

Comment: You should supply examples of what you have attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the most recent row for each `id`, then a convenient method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date)
                from t t2
                where t2.id = t.id
               );
```

With an index on `(id, date)`, this is likely to have very good performance.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without subquery or aggregators

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tracking t
LEFT JOIN tracking t2
  ON t2.id = t.id
  AND t2.date > t.date
WHERE t2.id is null
```

Here we use a left join to the same table by ID (if you want you can use more fields) and 
demand that the date be greater than that of t.
the row that cannot match this, is the biggest date of that id so we use the where t2.id is null to only show the not matching rows

- NOTE: if the biggest date is more that once for the same ID this query will bring all those rows.If u have a autoincremental id you can use that for the last one inserted 
  changing `AND t.date > t2.date` for `AND t.autoincremental_id > t2.autoincremental_id`