# Group By with an Over Clause for Date data

Tags: t-sql, date, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I'm still a junior when it comes to SQL and I was hoping to get some help from you on this.

I have data being summed cumulatively throughout a month and I'm trying to get the value matching the last day of the ISOWeek.

```
SELECT Date, [ISOWeek]
,SUM([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date) order by Date) AS [Value]

FROM [Demo].[MTD_Daily]
ORDER BY Date DESC

Date        ISOWeek Value
2020-07-19  2029    1006353.56
2020-07-18  2029    951399.59
2020-07-17  2029    895296.1
2020-07-16  2029    843615.05
2020-07-15  2029    793697.11
2020-07-14  2029    743885.91
2020-07-13  2029    687345.41
2020-07-12  2028    631264.57
2020-07-11  2028    576558.97
2020-07-10  2028    519336.1
2020-07-09  2028    468372.56
2020-07-08  2028    423332.98
2020-07-07  2028    371895.4
2020-07-06  2028    318428.22
2020-07-05  2027    265560.11
2020-07-04  2027    214018.45
2020-07-03  2027    159850.71
2020-07-02  2027    108456.77
2020-07-01  2027    53559.46
```

What I'm trying to get is this:

```
Date        ISOWeek Value
2020-07-19  2029    1006353.56
2020-07-12  2028    631264.57
2020-07-05  2027    265560.11
```

This is all I've been able to get

```
SELECT MAX(Date) AS Date
,MAX([ISOWeek]) AS [ISOWeek]
,SUM(SUM([Value])) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(MAX(Date)), MONTH(MAX(Date)) ORDER by DAY(MAX(Date))) AS [Value]

FROM [Demo].[MTD_Daily]
GROUP BY ISOWeek
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

However, this is what it yielded:

```
Date    ISOWeek Value
2020-07-19 00:00:00 2029    1111193.86
2020-07-12 00:00:00 2028    736104.87
2020-07-05 00:00:00 2027    370400.41
```

I can provide a .csv file with this data if it helps to reproduce this.

Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Larnu, I'm using the OVER clause to cumulatively sum my data daily each month. Can I achieve the same result in a different manner? Alternatively I can create a view with that and in there GROUP BY. I was trying to avoid having 2 views for this.

Comment: So you actually want the last row in each week? Does this answer your question? [Retrieving last record in each group from database - SQL Server 2005/2008](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4751913/2029983)

Comment: Fantastic Larnu, I've been at this for a couple days now. I managed to sort it by modifying the code in that post. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your existing query, you can rank records by descending `date` for each `ioweeek` in a subquery with `row_number()`, then use that information to filter in the outer query:

```
selet date, isoweek, value
from (
    select 
        date, 
        isoweek,
        sum(value) over (partition by year(date), month(date) order by date) as value,
        row_number() over(partition by isoweek order by date desc) rn
    from demo.mtd_daily
) t
where rn = 1
order by date desc
```

Comment: That gives me exactly what I need GMB. Larnu's post refers to very similar code which also helped. Thank you guys, you're fantastic.