# TSQL - Group by and sum not grouped column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I'm facing some kind of problem. I have table "Prices" with columns - ProductId, ShopId, Date, Price.
Table contains history of prices for products in diffrent shops. Each product can be in diffrent shop with diffrent price and Date.

I want to get sum of the lastest prices in all shops for each product.

```
| ProductId | ShopId |   Date     |  Price |
|:---------:|:------:|:----------:|:------:|
|     1     |   1    | 2020.11.10 |  100   |
|     1     |   2    | 2020.11.10 |  120   |
|     2     |   3    | 2020.11.10 |  200   |
|     3     |   3    | 2020.10.05 |  170   |
|     4     |   4    | 2020.11.10 |  200   |
|     4     |   4    | 2019.09.05 |  250   |
```

The output I want to get is (ShopId and Date can be included in output):

```
| ProductId | PriceSum |
|:---------:|:--------:|
|     1     |    220   |
|     2     |    200   |
|     3     |    170   |
|     4     |    200   |
```

I have following query:

```
SELECT ProductId, ShopId, MAX(Date) as MaxDate
FROM Prices
GROUP BY ShopId, ProductId
ORDER BY ProductId
```

Comment: Get the [Top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6841605/2029983)/[last row in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4751913/2029983) and then `SUM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution, not the fastest but working.

```
 select st.ProductId, SUM(st.Price)
 from Prices as p1 
 cross apply 
     (
        select ProductId, ShopId, MAX(Date) as MaxDate
        from Prices
        group by ShopId, ProductId
     ) as p2
 where p2.MaxDate = p1.Dt 
    and p2.Shopid = p1.ShopId
    and p2.ProductId = p1.ProductId
 group by p1.ProductId 
 order by p1.ProductId
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window function to identity the latest dates and filter out older recs

```
;With dat
As (SELECT ProductId, ShopId, Date , Price
         , row_number() over partition by prodictid, date order by date desc)r
FROM Prices)

Select Productid
           , sum(price) Pricesum
From dat
Where rid=1
Group by productid;
```

Comment: I don't think you want to partition by `Date` here.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

In your case `DENSE RANK` window function can help you. If two or more rows have the same rank value in the same partition, each of those rows will receive the same rank.

```
WITH LatestPricesCTE AS
(
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY Date DESC) Rank
    FROM Prices
)
SELECT ProductId, SUM(Price) PriceSum
FROM LatestPricesCTE
WHERE Rank = 1
GROUP BY ProductId
```

For more information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15