Query to get last position by User
I have the following table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PRC_PosizioniWalkers]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [idWalker] [int] NOT NULL,
    [username] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [data] [datetime] NULL,
    [Latitudine] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Longitudine] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_PRC_PosizioniWalkers] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


Now I need to write a query to get for every idWalker the last position. So to speak the result of the query should be:

What query do I need to write to get this result?

I m not able to write this query could you helpme?

Which dbms are you using? (The above SQL syntax is product specific. Perhaps MS SQL Server?)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751913/retrieving-last-record-in-each-group-from-database-sql-server-2005-2008

WITH RankedWalkers AS (
    SELECT 
        ID,
        idWalker,
        username,
        data,
        Latitudine,
        Longitudine,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY idWalker ORDER BY data DESC) AS rownum
    FROM 
        dbo.PRC_PosizioniWalkers
)
SELECT 
    ID,
    idWalker,
    username,
    data,
    Latitudine,
    Longitudine
FROM 
    RankedWalkers
WHERE 
    rownum = 1;


You can search for the latest by left joining to its pair having the same walker, but the "evenlater" is even later than the latest. If no such "evenlater" exists, then your record is indeed the latest.
SELECT
    latest.ID,
    latest.idWalker,
    latest.username,
    latest.data,
    latest.Latitudine,
    latest.Longitudine
FROM PRC_PosizioniWalkers latest
LEFT JOIN evenlater
ON latest.idWalker = evenlater.idWalker AND latest.data < evenlater.data
WHERE evenlater.idWalker IS NULL

Explanation:

we search for the latest for each idWalker
by disproving that an even later record would exist than the latest
so we search for a pair for this latest that would be newer
and filter any record where an even later pair was found
hence we get the latest position for each idWalker

